# I want to create a method in my enumeration?

Tags: java

I want to add a `toString` method to my `CustomerType` enumeration. My class returns a `System.out.println()` discount percent message if depending on my `cutomerType` which is now .20 because it is customerType college. I am new to enumerations and I want to be able to add a `toString` method to my enumeration that prints "College customer" depending on the customer type. Am having some trouble accomplishing this? What exactly am I doing wrong?

Hear's my Class:

```
import java.text.NumberFormat;
public class CustomerTypeApp
{
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    // display a welcome message
    System.out.println("Welcome to the Customer Type Test application\n");

    // get and display the discount percent for a customer type
    double Customer = getDiscountPercent(CustomerType.College);
    NumberFormat percent = NumberFormat.getPercentInstance();
    String display = "Discount Percent: " + percent.format(Customer);

    System.out.println(display);
}

// a method that accepts a CustomerType enumeration
public static double getDiscountPercent (CustomerType ct)
{
    double discountPercent = 0.0;
    if (ct == CustomerType.Retail)
        discountPercent = .10;
    else if (ct == CustomerType.College)
        discountPercent = .20;
    else if (ct == CustomerType.Trade)
        discountPercent = .30;

    return discountPercent;
}
}
```

and this is my enumeration:

```
public enum CustomerType {
    Retail,
    Trade,
    College;
    public String toString() {
        String s = "";
        if (this.name() == "College")
        s = "College customer";
        return s;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the error that you are getting?

Comment: At a glance this code looks fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enums are quite powerful to keep static data in one place. You can do something like that:

```
public enum CustomerType {

    Retail(.1, "Retail customer"),
    College(.2, "College customer"),
    Trade(.3, "Trade customer");

    private final double discountPercent;
    private final String description;

    private CustomerType(double discountPercent, String description) {
        this.discountPercent = discountPercent;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public double getDiscountPercent() {
        return discountPercent;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return description;
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks failing to follow the convention that Java constants are all uppercase. That made it much easier to catch students who submitted this as their own work.